How to Pass ADO Library to Azure Container Apps
The reference for AzureContainerApps@1 contains an argument environmentVariables which takes a string in space-separated {key}={value} format.
environmentVariables: foo=fooby bar=barby
// $foo -> "fooby, $bar -> "barby

You can pass yaml variables to this string, like so
environmentVariables: foo=($foo) bar=($bar)

However, this requires manually specifying every potential environment variable. How can I take all variables from an Azure Devops library and pass them to this function? Something like
variables:
  - group: myGroup

...
  - task: AzureContainerApps@1
    inputs:
      environmentVariables: $myGroup



I'm afraid there is currently no functionality to read all variables in Variable groups and pass them to Azure Container Apps task environment variables directly.
Workaround:
You can run the Rest API Variablegroups - Get to list all the variable names in Variable groups in a script task and add them to a list of strings.
Then, you can set it as variables in script and pass them to the Azure Container Apps task.
Example YAML with PowerShell script:
variables:
- group: myGroup  
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{groupId}?api-version=7.1-preview.2"
      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $(System.AccessToken)"}  -Method Get -ContentType application/json
      $myGroupVars = ""
      foreach ($var in $response.variables.PSObject.Properties) {
          $myGroupVars += "$($var.Name)=$($var.Value.value) "
      }
      Write-Host "$myGroupVars"
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myGroupVars]$myGroupVars"

- task: AzureContainerApps@1
  inputs:
    environmentVariables: '$(myGroupVars)'
    xxx: xxx

You can find the {groupId} in the URL of the variable group.

